# How to enable route security when using AngularFire with Angular ui-router?

Tags: firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

Is it possible to use the[AngularFire routeSecurity module](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/module.routeSecurity.js) with angular [UI-ROUTER](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of the standard ng-route provider? Is there a version of routeSecurity that would work with ui-router?

Comment: The angularFire-seed routeSecurity mod is written for ngRoute, and therefore won't work with ui-router. Nobody has written a module to integrate with ui-router yet, although that shouldn't prove particularly challenging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@mattvv Gave me this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mattvv/183e2a4073557b77ecb3) while I was talking on him in the angular irc channel. So essentially you would just need to replace the `routesecurity.js` file in angularfire directory assuming that you used yeoman to scaffold your application.

A neat thing to do is just to create another file named `routesecurity-ui-router.js` instead of replacing the content of the `routesecurity.js`.

So to give a little bit of information about the gist, basically mattvv just modified the `routes` term and use `state` instead.

Comment: +1 and thanks, those are helpful tips. I will look into the routesecurity.js file.

Comment: that is not just a tip, haha, it works!, I've came across that problem too, 7 days ago, just after you asked the question.

Comment: I agree its more than just a tip, :) I had somehow missed the link to the gist on the initial look. Marking this as answer. Thanks.