# Could not use ui router in angularFire-seed repo

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am using this repo:

```
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-angular-starter-pack/tree/master/angularFire-seed
```

as the starting point of my app and I would like to replace the native angular route with ui router.

However, the firebase connection will crash after I made the changes by replacing with ui router, here is the console message:

```
The connection to wss://s-dal5-nss-20.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=angular-fire-powder was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

After narrowing the scope (ui router package has been added successfully), also modified the routesecurity.js file with the following instruction: 
    [How to enable route security when using AngularFire with Angular ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058334/how-to-enable-route-security-when-using-angularfire-with-angular-ui-router)
, I really can't find where the problem is.

When I 'git stash' the following three files, the project will work:

```
modified:   app/index.html
modified:   app/js/module.routeSecurity.js
modified:   app/js/routes.js
```

Here are also there changes applied, pls kindly help!

app/index.html

```
   <ul class="menu">
-    <li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
+    <!-- <li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/chat">chat</a></li>
     <li ng-show-auth="logout,error"><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
-    <li ng-show-auth="login"><a href="#/account">account</a></li>
+    <li ng-show-auth="login"><a href="#/account">account</a></li> -->
+
+    <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
+    <li><a ui-sref="chat">chat</a></li>
+    <li ng-show-auth="logout,error"><a ui-sref="login">login</a></li>
+    <li ng-show-auth="login"><a ui-sref="account">account</a></li>
   </ul>
```

app/js/module.routeSecurity.js

```
 (function(angular) {
    angular.module('routeSecurity', [])
       .run(['$injector', '$location', '$rootScope', 'loginRedirectPath', function($injector, $location, $rootScope, loginRedirectPath) {
+         // if( $injector.has('$route') ) {
+         //    new RouteSecurityManager($location, $rootScope, $injector.get('$route'), loginRedirectPath);
+         // }
          if( $injector.has('$route') ) {
             new RouteSecurityManager($location, $rootScope, $injector.get('$route'), loginRedirectPath);
          }
       }]);

-   function RouteSecurityManager($location, $rootScope, $route, path) {
-      this._route = $route;
+   // function RouteSecurityManager($location, $rootScope, $route, path) {
+   function RouteSecurityManager($location, $rootScope, $state, path) {
+      // this._route = $route;
+      this._route = $state;
       this._location = $location;
       this._rootScope = $rootScope;
       this._loginPath = path;
```

app/js/routes.js

```
+   // .config(['$routeProvider', function($stateProvider) {
+   .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
+      // $routeProvider.when('/home', {
+      //    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
+      //    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
+      // });
+
+      // $routeProvider.when('/chat', {
+      //    templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
+      //    controller: 'ChatCtrl'
+      // });
+
+      // $routeProvider.when('/account', {
+      //    authRequired: true, // must authenticate before viewing this page
+      //    templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
+      //    controller: 'AccountCtrl'
+      // });
+
+      // $routeProvider.when('/login', {
+      //    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
+      //    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
+      // });
+
+      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
+
+      $stateProvider
+        .state('home', {
+          url: "/home",
+          templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
+          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
+        })
+        .state('chat', {
+          url: "/chat",
+          templateUrl: "partials/chat.html",
+          controller: 'ChatCtrl'
+        })
+        .state('account', {
+          url: "/account",
+          templateUrl: "partials/account.html",
+          controller: 'AccountCtrl',
+          data: {
+            authRequired: true, // must authenticate before viewing this page
+          }
+        })
+        .state('login', {
+          url: "/login",
+          templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
+          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
+        });
    }]);
```

The repo: https://github.com/yhjor1212/angular-fire-powder

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the doc, it was found that the following code should be changed:

from

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

to

```
<div ui-view></div>
```